# Advantage of introducing Isolatedprocess tag within Services in JellyBean[Android]

Tags: android

Can anyone put some light as what's the real/main advantage of introducing Isolatedprocess tag within Services in JellyBean[Android].
Is this advantageous at framework level or at the kernel level,as what we have seen that setting isolatedProcess tag value "true" within the Services assigns a new userId to that service process.

Answer (score 20):

Have you seen [Dianne Hackborn's](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/pk45eUFmKcM) answer on Google Groups? The question is identical and as she points out there is really one known use of that flags at this time: adding a layer of security for executing remote, untrusted code, i.e. JavaScript. There is no way to possibly guarantee that running remote code won't introduce security vulnerabilities, so by isolating the process that parses that code in a permission-less process, it becomes much more difficult for that code to do any real harm.